# Как ускорить выполнение моего кода JavaScript

Tags: javascript, оптимизация

Есть автомобили, которые движутся вправо, и мы обозначаем их «>», и автомобили, которые движутся влево, и мы обозначаем их «<». Существуют также камеры, которые обозначаются: «.».
Камера делает снимок автомобиля, если он движется в направлении камеры.

Нужно написать функцию, которая для входной строки, представляющей описанную дорогу, возвращает общее количество фотографий, сделанных камерами. Сложность должна быть строго O(N), чтобы пройти все тесты.

У меня не проходит один тест по времени, который должен выполняться не более 12 секунд. Как можно оптимизировать мой код?

```
Вот мое решение, оно работает корректно, но медленнее, чем того требуют тесты:

function countPhotos(road) {
    return road.split('').reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue, index, array) {
        if (currentValue == '.')
            accumulator += array.slice(index).filter(x => x == '<').length + array.slice(0, index).filter(x => x == '>').length;
        return accumulator;
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Как минимум у вас сложность O(N^2), так как вы внутри reduce проходитесь по всему массиву при каждом следующем элементе

Comment: Покажите несколько входных строк и желаемых результатов для них. Из описания не слишком понятно.

Comment: Yaant, примеры входных строк и результаты:
">>." -> 2 
 ".>>" -> 0 
">.<." -> 3 
 ".><.>>.<<" -> 11

Comment: хотел поставить + вопросу но кто-то минусанул, поэтому + на - дал 0 ) задачка интересная, на подумать

Answer (score 2):

Проходите по строке слева направо, подсчитывая знаки `>`. Когда встретили точку, добавляете к результату текущее значение счётчика.

Теперь проходите справа налево, подсчитывая знаки `<`. Когда встретили точку, добавляете к результату текущее значение счётчика.

Всё, линейная сложность обеспечена

Comment: Спасибо за объяснения)

Answer (score 2):

Когда речь заходит о скорости, забудьте о всяких красивых вещах. Можно сделать в один проход собирая нужную информацию и правильно выполняя операции исходя из данных.

```js
function countPhotos(road) {
    let result = 0;
    let countright = 0;
    let dots = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < road.length; i++) {
       let symbol = road[i];
       if (symbol === ">") {
          countright += 1;
       } else if (symbol === "<") {
          // эта машина пересекла все точки, которые мы нашли ранее
          result += dots;
       } else {
          dots += 1;
          // все машины едущие направо справа пересекли эту точку
          result += countright;
       } 
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(countPhotos(">>."))
console.log(countPhotos(".>>"))
console.log(countPhotos(">.<."))
console.log(countPhotos(".><.>>.<<"))
console.log(countPhotos(".<<.<<<.>."))
console.log(countPhotos("..>>>.<<<>>>.<<<..>>>..<<<.."))
```

Comment: приятно встретить единомышленника

Comment: @DaniilLoban, да, одинаковый подход получился)

Answer (score 2):

Задачу можно решить одним циклом (слева направо),просто нужно завести дополнительные переменные которые будут помнить количество пройденных камер (в цикле) и количество машин едущих слева на право. Вопрос сам по себе интересный

Решение:

```js
const calcSnapshots = (inp)=> {
      let count = 0
      let tempToRight = 0
      let leftCams = 0
      for (let i = 0; i < inp.length; i++){
        if (inp[i] === '>') tempToRight++ // cчитаем машины едущие вправо
        else if (inp[i] === '<') count += leftCams // машины едущие влево проедут все камеры слева
        else if (inp[i] === '.') {
          count += tempToRight // встречная камера встретит все машины слева
          leftCams+=1    // увеличиваем число камер оставшихся слева
        }
      }
      return count
    }
    
    const test = (pat, expect) => {
      console.log(pat, expect, 
        calcSnapshots(pat) === expect ? 'OK' : 'FAIL')    
    }
    test(">>.", 2)
    test(".>>", 0)
    test(">.<.",3)
    test(".><.>>.<<", 11)
    test(".<<<", 3)
    test("<.<<", 2)
    test("<<.>>", 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение. Оно работает за O(4*n) -> O(n).

```
let str = ".><.>>.<<";
let road = str.split("");
let totalLeftCars = road.filter(e => e === "<").length;
let totalRightCars = 0;
let leftPhotos = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < road.length; i++) {
    if (road[i] === ".") {
        leftPhotos += totalLeftCars;
    } else if (road[i] === "<") {
        totalLeftCars -= 1;
    }
}
let rightPhotos = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < road.length; i++) {
    if (road[i] === ".") {
        rightPhotos += totalRightCars;
    } else if (road[i] === ">") {
        totalRightCars +=1;
    }
}

console.log(leftPhotos + rightPhotos);
```

Comment: спасибо, теперь понятно в чем проблема была)